# Android hourglass

Tags: android, hourglass

How can I programmatically display an hourglass in an Android application?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use a [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html):

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setMessage("Thinking...");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

The above code will show the following dialog on top of your `Activity`:

[image]

Alternatively (or additionally) you can display a Progress indicator in the title bar of your `Activity`.

[image]

You [need to request this as a feature](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#configurewindowproperties) near the top of the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` using the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Then turn it on like this:

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

and turn it off like this:

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Comment: The problem is that after displaying the dialog box I ran a relatively long treatment which prevents the display of the dialog box that appears at the end of treatment when I no longer need !

Comment: Have a look at `AsyncTask`.  You display and hide the `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute` and do your work in `doInBackground`.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Might also be worth reading the Android Developer Guide "Designing For Responsiveness" http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Comment: The constructor ProgressDialog() is undefined . How to solve or what to replaced the "this" ?

Comment: @neobie Set "this" to the context that you want to display the Progress Dialog to.

Comment: every Android post older than 2 years should be wiped

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of doing it using AsyncTask:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        new MyLoadTask(this).execute(); //If you have parameters you can pass them inside execute method

    }

    private class MyLoadTask extends AsyncTask <Object,Void,String>{        

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public MyLoadTask(MyActivity act) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(act);
        }       

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();
        }       

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {         
            //Perform your task here.... 
            //Return value ... you can return any Object, I used String in this case

            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return(new String("test"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String str) {          
            //Update your UI here.... Get value from doInBackground ....
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }           
        }
    }
```