# Spinning wheel in Android

Tags: android

How can I spin a image wheel in an activity on android with the help of touch event? I need some guideline or link of any tutorial.

Comment: do you need to show it as animation or for progress?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140023/android-hourglass

Answer (score 3):

This is typically done with a couple pieces.  This is how I do it in one of my apps. *Note: This is not a smooth wheel, so much as it starts and stops at the top (which was intentional).  You can lookup more about `Animation` on the [dev site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html).

Main XML that has an image:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/anim_example"
    android:src="@drawable/loading_circle"
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:onClick="RunAnimation" />
```

Here are the parts in code that run the animation

```
public void RunAnimation(View v)
{
    //The onClick method has to be present and must take the above parameter.
    StartLoading();

    //This will delay the stop for 5 seconds
    //Normally you would want to actually have this run based on some other input/data.
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
          StopLoading(); 
        } 
    }, 5000); 
}

public void StartLoading() {
    ImageView refreshImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.anim_example);
    refreshImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loading_circle));
    Animation rotateLoading = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    refreshImage.clearAnimation();
    refreshImage.setAnimation(rotateLoading);
}

public void StopLoading() {
    ImageView refreshImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.anim_example);
    if (refreshImage.getAnimation() != null)
    {
        refreshImage.clearAnimation();
        refreshImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loading_circle));
    }
}
```

anim.rotate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="359"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%">
</rotate>
```